# If an OLS model is estimated without an intercept (no constant term) but the average residual is close to zero, are we OK?

Tags: regression, least-squares, residuals, assumptions

Let's suppose an OLS model is estimated without an intercept (no constant term), but the mean residual is very close to zero (2.2E-11) does that mean the model is OK to have been estimated without a constant term?

P.S.: All the variables are standardized to have zero mean and 1 standard deviation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constant term can be omitted if there is a strong reason to expect that the dependent variable has conditional mean zero at the average value for *all* covariates. Having said that, having a zero mean for residuals per se is insufficient to assess whether the OLS regression is well specified or not.  There are a battery of tests and analyses can be conducted for the assessment of an OLS regression.

Without going into the details of statistical inference on OLS, I refer to the introductory text of [Isman and Kim (2020)](https://moderndive.com/index.html)

Comment: Clarification should include if the average Y at the AVERAGE X (all of them) can be zero and is strongly implied by THEORY rather than the data. There is greater risk to omit the intercept when it is non-zero than to include it when it is zero. These decisions should not be based on the data.

Comment: @LSC so if the residuals sum very close to zero (2e-11) without the intercept, is it ok not to include the intercept?

Comment: @nyk I will accept your answer as long as someone does not post something contradictory to what you are saying. The variables are standardized to have mean zero and standard deviation 1, so I assume it is ok to estimate a model without intercept. Right?

Comment: @adrCoder My answer was edited as I had failed to mention the covariates (i.e. Xs), which was pointed out rightly by LSC and sheb.  If the dependent variable and the covariates (i.e.  Y and  Xs) are **all** standardized, it is OK to estimate the model without an intercept.

Comment: Yes all the variables are standardized to have zero mean. Please take a look at wording it needs a bit editing I think.

Comment: @adrCoder, in general, it is not acceptable to use the residuals for this purpose. By definition in OLS, the residuals will sum to zero, based on how the methodology works, so residuals sum to zero regardless of other conditions. I need to clarify my earlier comment-- when I said "average" I didn't mean standardizing; I meant "average" in the sense that the OLS function is an average for Y. SO really, omitting an intercept only makes sense if, when all X values are set to zero, the Y value (average Y) is zero. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 Standardizing the Y and Xs to zero mean does not satisfy this because it is not generally true that standardized X & Y leads to the average Y = 0 if all X are =0. It could be the case that all X (even standardized) set to 0 equals a standardized Y of 1 (or something else, nonzero).

Comment: @LSC so I can have non zero sum of residuals even though the variables are standardized to have zero mean?

Comment: So my initial comment doesn't need the word "AVERAGE" before "...X (all of them)..."

Comment: @adrCoder: by definition in OLS, the residuals will have a sum of zero. It tells you nothing of the underlying truth. OLS by definition finds the function so that sum of residuals is zero and so that sum of squared errors is minimized.

Comment: @LSC I thought without an intercept the sum of residuals may not be zero. No?

Comment: The basis of my answer (admittedly not clearly written) is that the OLS estimator of the intercept is $\hat{\beta }_{0}$=$\overline{y} $-$\hat{\beta }_{1}\overline{x}_{1} \ $-........- $\hat{\beta }_{p}\overline{x}_{p}$. Thus, from a computation view point (unless I got the formula wrong), there is no need to include an intercept in the regression model if the analyst knew before hand that $\overline{y}$ = $\overline{x}_{1}$=....=$\overline{x}_{p} =0.$  Anyhow, please feel free to edit the answer to make it clearer.